# Rails4: Ajax(ujs) is not working -confused

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I am getting `ActionController::UnknownFormat` when I click *link1* (Ajax request). Not sure why it does not generate `js` output.

According to Rails log, it is generating HTML!

```
Started GET "/sp/4/link1.html" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-12-18 14:07:09 +1100
Processing by PagesController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"4", "other"=>"link1"}
  Rendered pages/show.html.erb within layouts/application (0.2ms)
  Rendered shared/_leftnavigation.html.erb (0.2ms)
Completed 200 OK in 6ms (Views: 6.0ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

**pages_controller.rb**

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
def index
end
def show
    respond_to do |format| 
    #format.html 
    format.js
    end
end
end
```

**_leftnavigation.html.erb**

```
<div class="panel-body">
<%= link_to "link1(with Ajax)", root_url+"sp/4/link1.html", remote:true %>


       </div>

       <div class="panel-footer">
<%= link_to "link2(no Ajax)", root_url+"sp/3/link1.html" %>


       </div>
```

**show.html.erb**

```
<%= "<b> showproduct page...... </b>" %>
```

**show.js.erb**

```
$('#replacehere').html('<%= j render ("show") %>');
```

Note: `#replacehere` is defined in `layout/application.html.erb`

You could check my github repo for full source code.
**https://github.com/stackaccount/test**

It has a page controller and when user click link1(**app/views/shared/_leftnavigation.html.erb**) it should load `show.js.erb` and display  `show.html.erb`.

`format.html` works without any issue, but `format.js` does not wok.

I am struggling with  this issue for last two days. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that you have `jquery_ujs` in your `application.js`

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
```

Right now, your link ends with `.html` that forces your controller to respond with `html`. Because you commented out the `format.html` block so that exception was raised. To fix this, I think you have two ways:

1. Remove the `.html` at the end of your link
2. Using `format: 'js'` in `link_to`

Comment: Thanks Vutran. I have tried that. It does not work. Also, if I force js format, it will not fall back to html if js is disabled  in browser, I guess.

Comment: Can you paste the log of the request when you click to that link here? So I would have better look for it.

Comment: oh I think you didn't include `rails_ujs` to your view. See here https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs

Comment: I did. Please check my github repo. It is included in  assets/javascripts/application.js and in gem file (gem 'jquery-rails')

Comment: Excellent. You are the best :) I knew it something to do with the link. It is fixed but now issue is I will lose SEO if I remove .html or not?

Comment: as far as I know, `.html` doesn't have anything to deal with SEO. So don't worry about it.

Comment: Thanks for clarification.